# Amadeus Flight Search API

Tags: api, amadeus

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "38189",
            "title": "Internal error",
            "detail": "An internal error occured, please contact your administrator",
            "status": "500"
        }
    ]
}
```

I 'm getting the above error when I run an Amadeus Flight Search API on my mobile app. It was working perfectly before. Here is my API call: [https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=NBO&destination=MBA&departureDate=2018-08-25&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY&nonStop=false

What could be the issues?

Answer (score 1):

3 of our APIs:

- Flight Inspiration Search
- Flight Cheapest Date Search
- Flight Low-fare Search

Do **not** support the Content-Type "*application/json*".

Update your header to "*application/vnd.amadeus+json*" will solve the issue.

Note: We will update very soon those 3 APIs to support the Content-Type "*application/json*".

## EDIT:

All our APIs support the Content-Type application/json, you shouldn't have any problem anymore.

Comment: @anthony...thanks. Sending the issue via the developers email shortly..

Comment: Just incase there's anyone else who had/has the same issue, I changed the value of Content Type to "application/vnd.amadeus+json" and everything worked perfectly. Thanks to @anthony!